# snapshot id with filter boto3 within a For Loop

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, boto

I am trying to pass each snapshot id into for loop and print but to no avail, each time I can get to pass it only describes on the first snapshot and describes prints the tag for all.

```
for snapshot in get_my_snapshots():
    print ('Snapshot ID is equal to', snapshot['id'])
    my_tag = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:mytag', 'Values': ['TRUE']}])['Snapshots']
    print (my_tag)
    print('{:22} {:22}'.format(
        snapshot['id'],
        snapshot['description'],
        ))
```

Ive tried a number of combinations to pass in the snapshot id from the function but to no avail like below.

```
for snapshot in get_my_snapshots():
    print ('Snapshot ID is equal to', snapshot['id'])
    my_tag = ec2.describe_snapshots(SnapshotId=snapshot['id'], Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:mytag', 'Values': ['TRUE']}])['Snapshots']
    print (my_tag)
    print('{:22} {:22}'.format(
        snapshot['id'],
        snapshot['description'],
        ))
```

How can I pass the snapshot id into the describe with filter applied to get the tag for each snapshot

was able to resolve using function below and calling in for loop in main body

```
def get_tag_snapshots():
'''
Get all tags.
'''
global region_tags
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_tags)
snap_tag = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:mytag', 'Values': ['TRUE']}])
print ('Snap Tag!!', snap_tag)
ls_snaptags=[]
for snapshot in snap_tag['Snapshots']:
    (ls_snaptags.append(snapshot['SnapshotId']))
    snap_tag_id = snapshot['SnapshotId']
    yield {
        'snap_id': snapshot['SnapshotId'],
    }
    print ("Snapshot with mytag = True !! ",snapshot['SnapshotId'])
```

thank you for the help John

Comment: What is `get_my_snapshots()`? Can you edit your question to show a sample of what it is returning?

Comment: Why is the code specifying _both_ a `SnapshotId` _and_ a Filter? The Snapshot ID is unique, so that should be sufficient to retrieve details of the snapshot. If the snapshot does not have `mytag=TRUE`, it would be returning nothing. If you are wanting to "get the tag for each snapshot", then _do not_ specify a filter. All tags will be returned.

Comment: Im looking to exclude snapshots where mytag=TRUE. mu understanding is Filters parameter is for inclusion only, i am looking at filtering within for loop but getting issue on tag lookup, only seeing 'Description', 'OwnerId', 'SnapshotId' 'StartTime'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Find all snapshots that do not have a tag of `mytag=TRUE`

The simplest approach would be to use an `if` statement that checks the tags associated with the snapshot:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

for snapshot in ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])['Snapshots']:
    if 'Tags' in snapshot:
        # Skip if mytag=TRUE
        if [tag for tag in snapshot['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'mytag' and tag['Value'] == 'TRUE']:
            continue
    print(snapshot['SnapshotId'])
    print(snapshot['Description'])
```

The above code will print the ID and Description of any Snapshot that does *not* have a tag of `mytag=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

was able to resolve with function above and calling in for loop per snapshot